# Using same Resource with different levels of detail with Laravel

Tags: laravel

How do I use the same `Resource` with different attributes in Laravel?

Let's say I have a `User` and a `Post` model. In the `PostResource`, I also take use of the `UserResource`:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'body' => $this->body,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'image' => $this->image_url,
        'intro' => $this->intro,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'user' => new UserResource($this->user),
    ];
}
```

Here, the UserResource only needs to return a couple of attributes, such as:

```
return [
        'country' => $this->country,
        'image' => $this->image_url,
        'username' => $this->username,
    ];
```

But when using the `UserResource` in another scenario, for example a profile, I would need a lot more information about the user. I could create a `UserProfileResource` but that doesn't seem right to me.

So, what is the common practice/best solution for this?

Comment: Why would you want to use the same resource class for different scenarios? It's a good idea to use two resource classes.

Comment: @milo Thats not the idea of a resource. In the context of a shopping system is a sender a complete different resource than the resource of a user  – even if they are the same entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could create a UserProfileResource but that doesn't seem right to me.

Yes, you "should" be creating different resources for different responses needed/wanted. These resource classes are "cheap" so don't be afraid to make as many as you need.